# Plotting data from cassandra obtained via node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I have more than 5000 rows of data in cassandra (about 10000) that I want to plot using d3.js. I am currently using node.js to query cassandra. But there is a default limit to fetchSize from cassandra via node.js which is 5000. Is there a way to get all the data from cassandra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [several ways you can retrieve large amounts of data with the Node.js driver for Cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.0/nodejs-driver/reference/paging.html), that has built in support for streaming and throttling.

If you don't care about the time it spends retrieving an unbounded amount of rows to show the graph, you can just use `execute()` with a larger fetchSize.

```
client.execute(query, params, { prepare: true, fetchSize: 100000}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  renderGraph(result.rows);
});
```